# zebra stripes over riding my highlighting color

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to navigate through keyboard in table grid. In my code I have not added this zebra stripes coding. If I add this zebra stripes is overriding my highlighting.
eg: first row dark color and second row white color.I can see highlight through keyboard in first row but i can see in second row.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hKZqS/15/)

This coding for zebra stripes

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra']} );
```

I have an alternate solution is using border but how do i apply it here in my css

Comment: There's this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177690/zebra-stripes-over-riding-my-highlighting-color (I flagged it)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .tablesorter class to your CSS to make the selector more specific (thanks to Kobi for pointing it out) with something like this:

```
.tablesorter tr.ui-selected td { background: #f77; }
```

And to add a border something like this should work:

```
.tablesorter tr.ui-selected { border: 1px solid black; }
```

or more fancy:

```
.tablesorter tr.ui-selected { border: 2px dashed red; }
```

or something like that.

Comment: That rule will work even without `!important` - `.tablesorter tr.ui-selected td` is probably stronger anyway. Generally, I don't like to use `!important` unless I have to (for example, to override inline `style=""` rules).

Comment: @Kobi: You're right, after I added .tablesorter the !important is no longer necessary. Funny because I added it specifically to limit the !important. Oh, well... Thanks for pointing it out, I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Kobi::while i press key up and own it is not moving to next row but moving like this 5,10,15,20 record